# How to set 2 Kafka Docker containers in Windows 10

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have a challenge to complete. I have to set/mount 2 kafkas in 2 different docker containers (images). I have been able to install both containers but the problem is when i have to unify both ".yml" files in the same pc.

I mean: Kafka-manager runs in port 9000 to be configured. The first kafka docker, i have set is running in the port 9000, and i can admin it but the problem is when i want to set the second kafka docker image also with the kafka-manager, I don't know how to put other port to admin it.

As i have read all these things have to be done in the ".yml" files.

Hope you can understand my doubt and hope somebody can help with this problem, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kafka Manager should use bootstrap servers, or Zookeeper, not any one broker

Comment: Also, docker-compose can scale one kafka container into multiple instances, but your problem is Kafka Manager, not Kafka itself?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have two Kafka containers running on the same Docker host and have them both listen on port 9000?  You can publish ports with the Docker run `-p` option, but obviously two containers can't listen on the same port on the Docker host so you'll need to use port mappings - see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p-expose